# How to get "id" of an enhanced list view?

Tags: list-view

Please provide some idea on the below queries,

1. How many ways we can get an id for an enhanced list view other than from a standard view?.
2. If we need to create an enhanced list view for a custom object with record condition which 
   involves a field from parent Object, then how to create a view for this since the standard 
   view could not have a parent field to be included in the filter condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite sure I've understood you correctly, but for your first requirement you can actually retrieve a list view ID in Apex by using a StandardSetController for the object in question:

```
Database.QueryLocator ql = Database.getQueryLocator('select id from Custom__c');
ApexPages.StandardSetController setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(ql);
System.SelectOption[] listViews = setController.getListViewOptions();
String listViewID = null;
for(System.SelectOption listView : listViews)
{
    if(listView.getLabel() == 'Custom List View Name of Interest') 
    {
        listViewID = listView.getValue();
    }
}    
System.debug(listViewID);
```

For your second requirement, create a formula on the child object that pulls down the parent field to the child.

Comment: Thanks Phil for your time. But Is there an alternative approach available to create a custom view other than creating it using standard "Create new view" options under the tabs?. Which would also generate the id of the enhanced list?

I meant the same "Id" would be generated if possible using the above method as in the case if the view is created using a standard "Create New View" option under the particular object UI (tab).

Comment: Ah, ok so you wish to create a new List View from within your code? I think in that case then you will have to use the metadata API. Look at the work that @AndrewFawcett has done https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi. I'm afraid its not something I have tried personally.

Answer (score 0):

1 - [Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) or you can store the Id in a Custom Settings or Labels.
    To get the Id of a List View you can find it in the URL rendered when you select it  ...force.com/a02?fcf=yourListViewId

2 - You can achieve this by creating a formula field to get the parent object field and you can add it in the list view as a condition with no problem